# Always error authenticating through ADFS 2.0

Tags: adfs2.0

I've managed to setup two virtual machines in my local windows 7 laptop. Both of them are Windows server 2008 R2. One acts as Active Directory Domain controller and also as Active Directory Federation Services, and one other as the web app server. This second one is where I've set up my claims aware asp.net mvc web application and I also plan to setup ThinkTecture Identity Server later as my way to authenticate against custom username and password outside AD.

I've successfully implemented the installation and configuration needed for connecting our ASP.NET MVC apps through ADFS. They include :

1. Configure first server as Domain Controller and add domain account store (add user as testing -> this user belongs to Domain Users Group).
2. Configure first server also as active directory federation services.
3. configure relying party trust identifier from federation metadata generated from FedUtil.exe in second server.
4. Configure group claim mapping and assign Domain Users to this group.
5. Configure web apps server to be claims aware agent.

The one that's always troubled me is that every time I access my apps, it successfully prompts login dialog box. Once I enter My AD account and password, it always gives me the following error message : "There was a problem accessing the site. Try to browse to the site again.
If the problem persists, contact the administrator of this site and provide the reference number to identify the problem.
Reference number: c558ed55-b203-42cc-b6bd-3d66bddb96cd".

Any idea from you guys how to get this to work?? Any suggestion and ideas will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked in the event log?

Open Event Viewer > Go to Applications and Services Logs > AD FS 2.0

You'll see an list of errors which should give you some more guidance.

If you see the ADFS login screen, you can get to ADFS so I suspect it's something to do with your RP configuration.

Just to check - you are using ADFS 2.0 which you downloaded?